# C# Datatable linq condiction check

Tags: c#, function, dynamic, constructor, universal

I have created the function shown below. Everything is working fine, the challenge now, is that I have some scenarios where it would be ideal to have the constructor 'RadGridView grid' as a Datatable. I'm looking for a constructor that can take the input type of 'RadGridView' or type of 'Datatable' - a kind of "universal" constructor, if that is possiple?

```
public static void Export(RadGridView grid, string sheetName)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel file |*.xlsx";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                app.Visible = false;
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                worksheet.Name = sheetName;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range aRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
                workbook.Worksheets[1].Cells.NumberFormat = "@";

                for (int i = 1; i < grid.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = grid.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = grid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }

                aRange.Value = aRange.Value;
                aRange.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

                worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the 'dynamic' keyword.